# SQL Server suddenly not respecting default values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy

I am running a script to populate a table on an SQL Server 2017 database using SQLAlchamy. The script ran flawlessly a few weeks ago.

Essentially, the server does not seem to be populating default values on on non nullable fields.

For example, when I run the following statement (as rendered by SQLA):

```
 INSERT INTO concept
        (
                    retired,
                    short_name,
                    description,
                    form_text,
                    datatype_id,
                    class_id,
                    is_set,
                    creator,
                    date_created,
                    version,
                    changed_by,
                    date_changed,
                    retired_by,
                    date_retired,
                    retire_reason,
                    uuid,
                    note_regex
        )
        VALUES
        (
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?,
                    ?
        )'] [parameters: (0,
                    'ck',
                    'creatine phosphokinase',
                    None,
                    14,
                    49,
                    0,
                    0,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    None,
                    'cf6443ff-f2a1-49ab-96e3-c5d6fac362ed', None)]
```

I receive the error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'date_created',
table 'myositis_longetudinal_cohort.dbo.concept'; column does not allow
nulls. INSERT fails. (515)
```

This is confusing to me since the the date_created field has a default value of `getdate()`

Here is the constraint statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[concept]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__concept__date_cr__62AFA012] DEFAULT (Getdate()) FOR
[date_created]
```

I am new to SQL Server and am not sure what I may be missing. The server was update on 11/15/18, but I did not see anything in the update that could explain the change.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: A `DEFAULT`constraint only "kicks in" if you don't provide a value for it. You're providing it in your `INSERT` statement, and I *assume* passing the value `NULL`, hence the error. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1144b9f43c0a89d3b997994eb6c33af1)

Comment: On a unrelated note. Whitespace and line breaks are really important for making your SQL readable. Your `INSERT` statement isn't easy to read, as it's all on a single line.

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you! Is there a reason that this would have worked previously? That is the part that I am having a hard time wrapping my head around.

Comment: It shouldn't have worked before. Either your `INSERT` statement has been changed, or the NULLability of your column.

Comment: @Larnu, Thanks. I tend to work in Python instead of SQL so I was just pasting the raw output. I updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I'll expand my search to see if there were any updates in SQLAlchamy that might have changed how it is generating the SQL and if I can modify that behavior.

Comment: easiest way is go look at your table dbo.concept. Script it out and see what default constraints on any or all columns you have. Like suggested by @Lamu if you pass no value getdate() will get inserted

Comment: Simplify your example. Start with removing all non-problem columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO concept
    (
                retired,
                short_name,
                description,
                form_text,
                datatype_id,
                class_id,
                is_set,
                creator,
                date_created,  <--SPECIFYING HERE MEANS DEFAULT WON'T BE USED
                version,
                changed_by,
                date_changed,
                retired_by,
                date_retired,
                retire_reason,
                uuid,
                note_regex
    )
```

And the parameters:

```
[parameters: (
 0,                         <-- retired,  
 'ck',                      <-- short_name,     
 'creatine phosphokinase',  <-- description,                         
 None,                      <-- form_text,     
 14,                        <-- datatype_id,   
 49,                        <-- class_id,   
 0,                         <-- is_set,  
 0,                         <-- creator,  
 None,                      <-- date_created   (provided with NULL)  
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 'cf6443ff-f2a1-49ab-96e3-c5d6fac362ed', 
 None
 )]
```

The same problem will occur for any other columns in your table that have a NON_NULL_DEFAULT+NOTNULL_CONSTRAINT

As to possibilities why it's suddenly started happening:

- SQLAlchemy never used to generate an insert that specified this column
- The NOT NULL constraint was added
- A trigger supplying values in the case of a null being passed has been removed, re-coded or disabled

Comment: Thanks, it was a change in how the SQLA ORM __Table__ was setup!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone.

It turns out, that it was an SQLAlchemy issue.

I had to add `autoload: true` to my `__table_args__` instead of manually defining each Column. Apparently, If you do not allow SQLA to introspect the table, it will pass NULL as a value instead of skipping the value when generating the insert statement as suggested by @larnu and others.